The Kind of Man the World Claims to Admire
In the film Dr. Zhivago (1965) rogue, scoundrel and professional survivor, Victor Komorov meets young, firebrand revolutionary, Pasha Antipov. At the conclusion of the meeting Antipov departs and Komorov makes an assessment of the younger man:

"Pure. High-minded. The kind of man the world claims to admire but that it really despises."

For me, one of the best lines in this magnificent presentation about Russia in the first half of the 20th Century!
In Latin? It looks like an "of-such-a-kind-that" construction, given by  "qui", "is qui", "dignus qui" & "est/sunt qui" all with the subjunctive (when these are used indefinitely) e.g. "non sum is qui inimicos meos interficiam"--"I am not one to kill my enemies" literally--"of such a kind that I may kill my enemies" Oulton Book III, p.74.
In this example it's not the subject, Antipov, who is doing the admiring and despising, but the world. Therefore, is this construction to be used passively? The only passive, in this genre, I have found is this, in comments, from cnread, in Q:How to say "no one is worth to be believed (to) easily" with dignus+ supine? "nemo est dignus cui credatur"-- "no-one is worthy that he may be believed".
It might be easier to say that the world is of such a kind that....?

"Purus. integritas maximas. est is mundus qui illos viros admirari simulet, sed vere eos despiciat,"--


"Pure. The greatest integrity. The world is of such a kind that it may pretend to admire these men, but it really despises them,".

In the English version "claim" means "pretend" i.e. declare falsely. In Latin "postulo", "flagito", "exposco", which Oxford lists for "claim" do not appear to have this context.
Fortunately, "mundus"--"world", in Latin, can be used to mean "mankind", as in English.
My confidence in this translation is low. What should it be?

Why change the subject and use a passive rather than just changing qui to quem "whom"?

@TKR: Is this: "est is quem mundus admirari simulet, sed vere  despiciat," what you mean?

Yes, that's the structure I meant -- it seems closest to the original.

@TKR: Thank you. It was easy, then? Guess I over-thought it.
